# Emgu circle detection using a webcam

Tags: webcam, detection, geometry, emgucv

I'm trying to write a program that detects a circle when you hold it in front of the webcam. I know how the circle detection works for an image, but I can't figure out how to get it to work with a webcam stream, using the following code:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer(); //create an image viewer
        Capture capture = new Capture(); //create a camera capture
        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  //run this until application closed (close button click on image viewer)
            Image<Bgr, Byte> image = capture.QueryFrame();
            //MemStorage storage = new MemStorage();
            //Contour<Point> contours = image.FindContours();
           //Contour<Point> currentContour = contours.ApproxPoly(contours.Perimeter * 0.05, storage);
            viewer.Image = image; //draw the image obtained from camera
        });
        viewer.ShowDialog(); //show the image viewer
}
```

As you can see I've tried using FindContours in the innermost loop but the program just freezes when I try running it, so I commented that particular part out. Can anyone tell me how to implement circle detection using a webcam?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HoughCircle` Method for circle detection

```
Image gray = img.Convert().PyrDown().PyrUp();

Gray cannyThreshold = new Gray(180);
Gray cannyThresholdLinking = new Gray(120);
Gray circleAccumulatorThreshold = new Gray(120);

CircleF[] circles = gray.HoughCircles(
    cannyThreshold,
    circleAccumulatorThreshold,
    5.0, //Resolution of the accumulator used to detect centers of the circles
    10.0, //min distance 
    5, //min radius
    0 //max radius
    )[0]; //Get the circles from the first channel
```

See Method [`HoughCircle`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/6f78c3d8-fb1a-5983-2862-549c49019d49.htm)